# Why am I getting a "missing argument for parameter" error in this code?

Tags: swift

I have a error in Swift: "Missing argument for parameter 'bundle' in call"

```
Class Radio : UIViewController {
    let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")

    @IBAction func newButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
        var streamer = Radio.alloc().init(url!)
    }
}
```

I don't really understand this error so if someone can help.

Comment: Don't use alloc/init in Swift. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: I tried but I think i wrong, I'm trying to translate this to swift

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedValue];
  streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to initialize your `Radio` class with a parameter which is `url`.

But this class doesn't have an `init(url: NSURL)` (or at least it's not shown in your question) so you can't.

You need to create an `init(url: NSURL)` and inside this init you also have to call the super init for `UIViewController` (even if you don't use it, as in my example) since your `Radio` class inherits from it.

This is why you get this error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'bundle' in call

because Xcode suggests to use the `init(nibName: String?, bundle: NSBundle?)` initializer for the class since it's the only one available.

So, keeping your code example as a base, you could do something like this to make it work:

```
class Radio : UIViewController {

    var url = NSURL(string: "someDefaultURL")

    init(url: NSURL) {
        self.url = url
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func newButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let newURL = NSURL(string: "myurl")
        let streamer = Radio(url: newURL!)
        // do something with `streamer`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `var streamer = Radio` then type `(` and wait for Xcode hint the constructor methods. I guess maybe this method will be `var streamer = Radio(url:url!)`.

Comment: i tried var streamer = Radio(url:url!) and var streamer =  Radio().init(url: url!) but I always have  "missing argument in parameter"

Comment: Locate the `Radio` class and see the `constructor` methods. You can post these methods here. So, we will convert these methods for you.